# How to compare and manipulate json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays, json

I need to compare and manipulate JSON objects.

### First object

```js
let data1 = {
  "id": "111",
  "entity_id": "222",
  "text_id": "333",
  "details": [{
    "value": 1000,
    "comp_id": "444",
    "CompName": "driving"
  }]
}
```

### Second object

```js
let data2 = [{
  "id": "111",
  "text_id": "333",
  "criteria_type": "TXT",
  "value": 1000,
  "comp": {
    "id": "444",
    "name": "driving"
  }
}, {
  "id": "222",
  "text_id": "444",
  "criteria_type": "TXT",
  "value": 2000,
  "comp": {
    "id": "555",
    "name": "swiming"
  }
}]
```

There are 2 objects `data1` and `data2`. Here, I need to compare the `data1.details` array with the `data2` array key => `data1.details.comp_id` with `data2.comp.id` if not match then I need to push `value`, `id` and `name` to `data1` object. Please help me to resolve this issue.

### Resulting object

`data1` will be:

```js
{
  "id": "111",
  "entity_id": "222",
  "text_id": "333", 
  "declaration_details": [{
    "value": 1000,
    "comp_id": "444",
    "CompName": "driving",
  }, {
    "value": 2000,
    "comp_id": "555",
    "CompName": "swiming",
  }]
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `filter()` to find objects in the `data2` matching `comp.id`. Then you can just use `map()` to create a new array. Finally, you can add the `mappedData2` array to the `data1` in `declaration_details`.

```js
let filteredData2 = data2.filter(item => {
  return data1.details.some(detail => detail.comp_id === item.comp.id);
});
let mapData = filteredData2.map(item => {
  return {
    value: item.value,
    comp_id: item.comp.id,
    CompName: item.comp.name
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expected result, wouldn't you just need to map `data2` to the `declaration_details` of the resulting object?

```js
const main = () => {
  const { details, ...rest } = data1;
  const result = {
    ...rest,
    fbp_year: new Date().getUTCFullYear(),
    declaration_details: data2.map(({
      value,
      comp: {
        id: comp_id,
        name: CompName
      }
    }) => ({
      value,
      comp_id,
      CompName
    }))
  };
  console.log(result);
};


const
  data1 = {
    "id": "111",
    "entity_id": "222",
    "text_id": "333",
    "details": [{
      "value": 1000,
      "comp_id": "444",
      "CompName": "driving"
    }]
  },
  data2 = [{
    "id": "111",
    "text_id": "333",
    "criteria_type": "TXT",
    "value": 1000,
    "comp": {
      "id": "444",
      "name": "driving"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "222",
    "text_id": "444",
    "criteria_type": "TXT",
    "value": 2000,
    "comp": {
      "id": "555",
      "name": "swiming"
    }
  }];
  
main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JSON.stringify(yourJsonObject) to convert your objects to strings.
Then you can compare them like this. `areEqual = string1 == string2`. Make sure the object properties are in the same order for both objects.